# I'm having an issue with div placement

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so I am using bootstrap and trying to create a scenario where half the row is orange, the other half green, but directly in the middle I want the blue hexagon.
The problem I'm having is I can get the blue hexagon to sit in the center on desktop but I want to design it mobile friendly. Any ideas how I could get the hexagon to sit directly in the middle were the two divs meet and stay there when in mobile friendly too?

here's my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
 <title>Hexagon | Home</title>

 <!-- Bootstrap -->
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arima+Madurai" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Shade" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
 <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
 </head>

 <body>
    <header>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6  red-500">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 green-500">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-6 hex-cont">
                        <div class="hexagon">
                            <i class="fa fa-handshake-o logo" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:7em;"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 white">
                    <h1 class="text-center wit">Friend Zone</h1>
                    <h3 class="text-center wit">Mediation Service</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </header>
```

and here's my relevant CSS

```
body{


font-family: 'Arima Madurai', cursive;
}

.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 115.47px;
  background-color: #64C7CC;
  margin: 57.74px 0;
  display:block;
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 57.74px solid #64C7CC;
}

.hexagon:after {
  top: 100%;
  margin-left:-83%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 57.74px solid #64C7CC;
}

.red-500{
    background:#FF4500;
    height:250px;
    z-index:0;
    display:block;
}

.green-500{
    background:#4CA64C;
    height:250px;
    z-index:-5;

}
```

Comment: A fiddle would do you a lot of justice for this type of question, FYI

Comment: Hi, I would use the hidden-xs hidden-sm for the larger devices then have another version suited for mobile with hidden-md hidden-lg classes Bootstrap provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've made the row with orange/green, put the hexagon element in that row, add `position: relative;` to the row (parent), set the hexagon element to `position: absolute;` and use a combination of `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` to center it.

```css
body{


font-family: 'Arima Madurai', cursive;
}
.row {
  position: relative;
}
.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 115.47px;
  background-color: #64C7CC;
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 57.74px solid #64C7CC;
}

.hexagon:after {
  top: 100%;
  margin-left:-83%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 57.74px solid #64C7CC;
}

.red-500{
    background:#FF4500;
    height:250px;
    z-index:0;
    display:block;
}

.green-500{
    background:#4CA64C;
    height:250px;
    z-index:-5;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
 <title>Hexagon | Home</title>

 <!-- Bootstrap -->
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arima+Madurai" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Shade" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
 <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
 </head>

 <body>
    <header>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6  red-500">
                </div>
                                      <div class="hexagon">
                            <i class="fa fa-handshake-o logo" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:7em;"></i>
                        </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 green-500">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-6 hex-cont">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 white">
                    <h1 class="text-center wit">Friend Zone</h1>
                    <h3 class="text-center wit">Mediation Service</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Shouldn't .hexagon:after have  margin-left: -63%;

Comment: @Nick_O I dunno, I just copied and pasted that from OP's code, and the before/after parts of the hexagon shape wasn't part of OP's question.